# Webpack & React - Change data of json file without the need to rebuild

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, ecmascript-6

I am trying to create an app with some universal variables stored in a JSON that I can change without the need to rebuild.

So I created this very basic structure

`src/index.js`

```
import data from '../assets/variables.json'
console.log('test');
console.log(data);
```

`assets/variables.json`

```
{"price":20}
```

I go ahead and build a `dist/main.js` file which I include in a WordPress plugin. So far so good.

If I want to change the price to {"price":30}, for example, I need to rebuild the webpack bundle. I want an alternative that doesn't require a local rebuild.

I failed to understand WebPack's Externals. Can I include the data from there?
Can I somehow fetch them on ComponentDidMount? Do I need an API for that or just the file's URL?

Is there a better option? Long story short I want a non-technical user to be able to update the basic data.

Thank you for any ideas.

Comment: webpack is basically there to make a bundle of all your js files. (this needs a build) If you want a js file, that should be included without build, i would suggest just including it in the html head manually and exclude it from your build files. Therefor it would not be included in your weppack bundle and just load as a single js file, and all the values can be updated without the need of a build.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `fetch API` to fetch data from a JSON file without `importing` it. Use the method below:

```
const fetchData = async filePath => {
    try{
        const res = await fetch(filePath);
        return await res.json();
    }catch(err){
        return err;
    }
}
```

Keep in mind that since you are only fetching the data on `componentDidMount` and since you do not rebuild everytime the json file content is changed, you will not see the updated values. Make a button `fetch` the json data. That way user can press the button after changing the json file.